# Временые зоны, даты в js и google sheets aps script

Tags: google-apps-script

При создании новой Таблицы, если поместить в ячейку значение времени "9:00", то она станет временем и будет выглядеть так

```
Sun Dec 31 1899 09:00:00 GMT+1000 (AEST)
```

Но есть Лист, где в ячейке стоит 9:00, а хранится как

```
Sun Dec 31 1899 03:00:00 GMT+1000 (AEST)
```

Проблема всплыла при попытке скопировать через gs значение из одной ячейки в другую

```
.getValue().getHours()
```

приходит 3 вместо 9.

- Вопрос как получить именно то, что видит пользователь в ячейке через gs? * Как понять программно что у него там отображается?
- Второстепенный вопрос как это случилось и как от этого избавиться, привести например всё к одному поясу?

Я нахожусь в поясе GMT+10.

Comment: Как оказалось получить то что видит пользователь можно с  getDisplayValue(). По остальным вопросам всё ещё не понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы получить отображаемые данные, необходимо вызвать метод [getDisplayValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalue) класса Range.

Копирование даты

```
function moveTime() {
  var spreadsheetFrom = SpreadsheetApp.openById("...");
  var rangeFrom = spreadsheetFrom.getSheets()[0].getRange("A1");
  var valueFrom = rangeFrom.getValue();
  var spreadsheetTo = SpreadsheetApp.openById("...");
  var rangeTo = spreadsheetTo.getSheets()[0].getRange("A1");
  rangeTo.setValue(valueFrom);

  Logger.log(spreadsheetFrom.getSpreadsheetTimeZone());
  Logger.log(spreadsheetTo.getSpreadsheetTimeZone());
}
```

Вывод

```
[18-03-01 17:37:16:795 MSK] Atlantic/Bermuda
[18-03-01 17:37:16:796 MSK] Europe/Minsk
```

В Таблицах

- в первой 01.03.2018 18:10:02
- во второй 3/2/2018 1:10:02

Изменение времени.
**Внимание!!! Данные будут изменены**

```
function stornoTime() {
  var spreadsheetFrom = SpreadsheetApp.openById("...");
  var rangeFrom = spreadsheetFrom.getSheets()[0].getRange("A1");
  var valueFrom = rangeFrom.getValue();
  var spreadsheetTo = SpreadsheetApp.openById("...");
  var rangeTo = spreadsheetTo.getSheets()[0].getRange("A1");
  rangeTo.setValue(valueFrom.addHours(-7));

  Logger.log(spreadsheetFrom.getSpreadsheetTimeZone());
  Logger.log(spreadsheetTo.getSpreadsheetTimeZone());

}

Date.prototype.addHours = function(h) {
  this.setTime(this.getTime() + h * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  return this;
}
```

В Таблицах

- в первой 01.03.2018 18:10:02
- во второй 3/2/2018 18:10:02

Как "нормально" определить размер сторнирования не понятно.

Скрипт возвращает дату в том времени, в котором он настроен. Настройки времени скрипта находятся в Menu => File => Project properties => Time zone

### Пример

```
function getLocalTime() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("...");
  var range = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0].getRange("A1");
  var value = range.getValue();
  var displayValue = range.getDisplayValue();
  Logger.log(Session.getScriptTimeZone());
  Logger.log(spreadsheet.getSpreadsheetTimeZone());
  Logger.log(value);
  Logger.log(displayValue);
}
```

Данные в ячейке "**01.03.2018 18:10:02**"

- Для скрипта "**Africa/Sao_Tome**" GMT+1
- Для Таблицы "**Europe/Luxembourg**" GMT+1

получим

```
[18-03-01 17:13:17:998 MSK] Africa/Sao_Tome
[18-03-01 17:13:17:998 MSK] Europe/Luxembourg
[18-03-01 17:13:17:999 MSK] **Thu Mar 01 18:10:01 GMT+01:00 2018**
[18-03-01 17:13:17:999 MSK] 01.03.2018 18:10:02
```

- Для скрипта "**Asia/Kamchatka**" GMT+12
- Для Таблицы "**Europe/Moscow**" GMT+3

получим

```
[18-03-01 17:18:17:243 MSK] Asia/Kamchatka
[18-03-01 17:18:17:244 MSK] Europe/Moscow
[18-03-01 17:18:17:245 MSK] Fri Mar 02 03:10:01 GMT+12:00 2018
[18-03-01 17:18:17:245 MSK] 01.03.2018 18:10:02
```

### Вывод

Делать ничего не нужно, время указывается корректно. Причина отображения разного времени из-за того, что пользователи смотрят в разные Таблицы с разными часовыми поясами.